# transaction.serialize is not a function

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, metaplex-js

I use:

```
**await metaplex.connection.sendTransaction(signedTxs)**
```

but have this error:

```
**transaction.serialize is not a function at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction**
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Could you share more code?

Comment: What version of the metaplex sdk are you using? Can you share the code you are creating the `signedTxs` with?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you could try [this](https://www.soldev.app/course/serialize-instruction-data) or  https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Transaction.html
First one is the borsh serialize method